# Flutter not load assets

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a problem with flutter the assets below are not displayed inside the widget, it tells me unable to load assetss how can I do to fix this?

**Dart Code:**

```
final cookingEvent = Event(
    imagePath: "assets/event_images/granite_cooking_class.jpeg",
    title: "Basket",
    description: "",
    location: "Ferrara(FE)",
    duration: "1ms",
    punchLine1: "Partecipa!",
    punchLine2: "nuova partita di calcio",categoryIds: [0, 2],
    galleryImages: ["assets/event_images/cooking_1.jpeg", "assets/event_images/cooking_2.jpeg", "assets/event_images/cooking_3.jpeg"]);
```

**Flutter Exception:**

```
r:   "assets/event_images/5_km_downtown_run.jpeg", scale: 1.0)
flutter: ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
flutter: Another exception was thrown: Unable to load asset: assets/event_images/granite_cooking_class.jpeg
flutter: Another exception was thrown: Unable to load asset: assets/event_images/music_concert.jpeg
flutter: Another exception was thrown: Unable to load asset: assets/event_images/golf_competition.jpeg
```

**Pubspec.yaml:**

```
assets:
   - assets/guest_images/
   - assets/event_images/
   - assets/fonts/

fonts:
    - family: Montserrat
      fonts:
          weight: 700
```

Comment: Make sure the image path is correct and restart the application. Not hot-restart / reload. Close the app and run again.

Comment: i have try but i havd always error

Comment: Silly question: have you already run flutter pub get?

Comment: Can you make sure this file exists in the directory?  assets/event_images/5_km_downtown_run.jpeg  Check the spelling correctly

Comment: Yes file existing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Make sure that the path of your image is correct.
2. Then check for tab spaces.

[image: an example for point 2]

3. make sure to run *flutter pub get* command.
4. Then restart your app or hot reload your app.